# TimeZoneInfo lock contention

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timezone, locking

Our system handles multiple streams of real-time calculations in parallel - roughly 300-500 calculations a second. We're seeing an occasional issue in production where the ThreadPool expands out to 400-500 threads, and performance drops to a crawl. The calculations are still continuing, but at a much slower rate.

Process dumps + Parallel Stacks window in VS shows several hundred threadpool threads with call stacks that all end in a `Monitor.Enter` in TimeZoneInfo. Our calculations involves timezone conversion.

I would have thought we should be able to acquire that lock thousands or millions of times a second without issue. The fact a few hundred threads are backed up by this lock is surprising. The fact the app continues to process work implies this isn't deadlock, just very costly contention.

Here's an example callstack - all of the threads are variations on this:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(object obj, ref bool lockTaken) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(System.DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfoOptions flags)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.DateTime.ToUniversalTime()  Unknown
<our code>
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)  Unknown
...
```

We're running .Net 4.0. It looks like the locking implementation in TimeZoneInfo has changed in .Net 4.5 - there is a lot less locking in 4.5.

Searching on this problem hasn't yielded much. It looks like there may have been a fix for this in .Net 4.5. Does anyone have any knowledge possibly related to this?

Comment: Have you considered using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) instead?  It's optimized for perf, and works on .NET 3.5+

Comment: It's not something we've looked at. The timezone work is only a small part of the cost of our calculations... except when we're getting bottlenecked by the locking. Our tests are showing the .Net 4.5 version is quite a bit faster.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar on 4.6.2. Did you ever find a solution to this, or did you just work around it? (I'm considering NodaTime)

Comment: Never found a proper solution. The server hardware was pretty old and the machine was struggling under the load. We got new hardware, which made the service much healthier, and we didn't notice the issue again. Doesn't mean it actually went away, though. Sorry for the unsatisfying answer.